# A weird vanishing website when scrolling up (only in Chrome)

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

So this is a bit weird. (only) In **Chrome** browser, when scrolling back up to the top (with two fingers rather than the sidebar), my content seems to vanish.
It becomes visible again upon scrolling back down.
I'm attaching a screenshot as some of you may not see the bug.
[image: website before the bug]
[image: website when scrolling to top with two fingers in chrom]

my website address: https://londonim.co.il
I switched to called CuteWP which is the root to all these new problems.

I suspect there is something to do with the opacity settings and animation for webkit, along with the sticky navmenu because when I inspect it on developer mode, I can see that 
   `<div class=cutewp-scroll-top'>` is getting a `display:none` property.

however I cannot be sure that this is the issue. My best guess lies within the styling code for the scroll bar. however this is a mere guess and fiddling with the opacity here remained fruitless.
Here's the code of my prime suspect:

```
/* Scroll to Top Button
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.cutewp-scroll-top{background:#000000 left top no-repeat url(assets/images/scroll-top.png);border:1px solid black;cursor:pointer;display:block;height:29px;opacity:.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);position:fixed;bottom:20px;right:20px;width:29px;z-index:200;}
.cutewp-scroll-top:hover{opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);-webkit-transition:opacity 1s;transition:opacity 1s;}

.cutewp-box{background:#fff;padding:15px;border:1px solid #dddddd;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;}
.cutewp-animated{-webkit-animation-duration:2s;-moz-animation-duration:2s;-o-animation-duration:2s;animation-duration:2s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}
@-webkit-keyframes cutewp-fadein{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes cutewp-fadein{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}
@-o-keyframes cutewp-fadein{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}
@keyframes cutewp-fadein{from{opacity:0;}to{opacity:1;}}
.cutewp-fadein{-webkit-animation-name:cutewp-fadein;-moz-animation-name:cutewp-fadein;-o-animation-name:cutewp-fadein;animation-name:cutewp-fadein;}
```

I have also noticed that when the error occures
`<div class="cutewp-container cutewp-primary-menu-container clearfix cutewp-fixed">` changes to `<div class="cutewp-container cutewp-primary-menu-container clearfix">` however i cannot find the command line for this change.

Would appreciate the help with this, although I realize this is a bit more vague than the way one should normally ask a question.

Thanks a lot,

Joni

Comment: is this solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue with `overflow` with websites. To mitigate this kind of issue you just have to add in your **`custom css`** settings this code:

```
body {overflow:hidden !important;}
```

This will apply hiding `overflow`(s) to avoid unnecessary scroll tab.

Comment: you meant `body {overflow:hidden !important;}` of course. That did the trick - many thanks!!!

Comment: @joni_dee yeah sorry for the typo :)

Comment: no prob, you helped me a lot. Also these typos are good they screen out freeloaders who have zilch idea re code :-)